# Personal wedding day of a colleage employee and cultural anomaly

Tags: colleagues, employees, sri-lanka

I was invited to a wedding day of a friend in my workplace(another engineer who works with me in the same engineering department). Due to the busy schedules I was unable to find some time to meet him and personally politely reject that invitation. Now I have to attend the wedding tomorrow.

According to the local culture the people who participate in the wedding should give some amount of money as a gift. Now the problem is I don't have that money (true that my salary is around 10 times of that money, but I have already allocated that money for my higher education, since every penny counts and living cost is high here). 
So what I'm asking is, what will be the consequences if I don't attend that wedding? Will that made a unfriendly work-environment for me? That's the last thing that I need.

What else should I do? Such as write a email to the friend that I'm not attend his wedding politely? What is the most polite thing to do now?

Comment: Will you have that money at a later date, or would you prefer to not spend it at all?

Comment: @nvoigt I have that money at my account now. Yes I'm not prefer to spend it so I could spend it on my higher education. I need higher education because I need to climb higher in my career ladder.

Comment: I would just go to the wedding and not hand over the money. Traditions are there to be broken. Besides the person will be more adsorbed with the wedding that worry about trivial things.

Comment: What happens if you get sick? What does your cultural habits say about the gift in that case?

Comment: @nvoigt they are trying to collect money after the wedding, and that sucks. However would you suggest to write a sick letter ? It's not a issue at all since the wedding day is not an official working day.

Comment: people are giving 5000/-RS ( around 35USD).
But compared with my local salary in Sri Lanka , that also a big amount, even for a device driver engineer. :( but you can just give 10$ or less than 10$ and walk away. But the thing is there's a little bit shame on that.

Comment: I mean I need to find a way to escape from that shame as well as from paying it.

Comment: You really need to tell us what culture that is. I could give you an answer that applies to the UK, and that won't be any use of you.

Comment: I don't see how this is in any way connected with the Workplace. Why would any answer be different if this was someone you knew personally rather than through work?

Comment: This is a personal situation and the workplace link is too nebulous for it to be on-topic here. Next time, maybe don't forget to decline the invitation because I really don't buy "I was too busy" as an excuse.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about navigating personal instead of professional relationships.

Comment: Finally I went to the party. And managed to give small amount of money in an envelope. Yes you are right, professional people and when it comes to professional relationship, people just only talk about how much they give but NOT how much I didn't give. That's the nature of professional highly competitive workplace. I can't add my experience as an answer for somebody who dig this thread in future cos this is on hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My culture expects people to do without and get loans to contribute to such events and a whole lot of backstabbing goes on over how much and who didn't etc,.

However you're an outsider, you're not obligated to do so since you're not part of the cultural exchange system and extended family. Feel free to attend and give something small as a gift or nothing at all. No one will think the worse of you, they'll be busy weighing up their own people's contributions.

As far as cultural obligations and expectations go, you're basically asking how to flout them without repercussions. It doesn't work like that, but I wouldn't worry about it if I were you, flouting them with strangers is fine. You will never receive it back from them which is the whole point of contributing. You have to be pragmatic if you want to get ahead in life.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously culture will come into play, but my answer would be to not attend the wedding, and just turn up to work on Monday. When the person asks where you were, say that your schedule was so busy that you didn't get a chance to meet them in person and tell them that you couldn't attend (no reason to explain why you couldn't attend). Their response will determine if they are going to remain a friend or not, and there's nothing you can control about that.

There is ABSOLUTELY NO WAY I would consider a wedding gift to ANYONE that would take 10% of my salary. I don't care who they are, or what the culture is. Especially as that money is earmarked for your education; risk your future for a wedding gift? Nah...

Comment: So, no way 10% right ?

Comment: I mean normally people give around 20$ gift right in US ? Then so it's about 20/7K *100% right ? around 0.2% right ? 
But I've handover a gift more than that. around which is 2.5 % of my salary. However relationships like these are more coupled than in US, So what you think 2.5% is more reasonable right ?

Comment: @Pete some cultures it is obligatory, my own would expect at least a whole weeks normal pay (whether you actually have a job or not) and repercussions would involve your whole extended family being shamed. However unless you're part of the particular cultural exchange group it's not very important.

Answer (score 4):

In my culture, if you didn't respond to a wedding invitation, it is assumed that you will *not* be attending... So I would just settle for congratulating them when they come back to work. There also isn't an obligation to give a gift if you didn't attend one of our weddings (except, perhaps for relatives); it'd be entirely up to you to decide whether and how large a gift was appropriate if you didn't attend.

Things may be different elsewhere.

And some workplaces have a strong tradition of taking up a voluntary collection in the office to get the co+worker a group gift; typically that's only about $20 per person or less.